# Is there a way to retrieve the number of members in a group using the Keycloak API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am using Keycloak API and I have a use case where I need to get the number of members in a group, before fetching all users.

Unfortunately, both endpoints `GET /{realm}/groups/{id}/members` and `GET /{realm}/groups/{id}` do not return such information.

The API doc on https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html does not seem to indicate how we can get the count.

So, how we can get this information using the Keycloak API ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, one does not have an endpoint like `GET /{realm}/groups/{id}/members/count` like one has for the number of groups (*i.e.,* `GET /{realm}/groups/count`).

What you would need to do, is to define `max` query parameter to `-1` so that you are sure to get all the members using the endpoint `GET /{realm}/groups/{id}/members` and then just count the number of members on the `json` response. Of course, this is a sub-optimal approach, but the only one using the API as it is.

---

I have provided a complete script that automatizes this processes in the following [repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Groups/getNumberElementsInGroup.sh).

Comment: Can we get the group members by specifying group name and not the id?

Comment: @SoumeeGiri No, As far as I can see on the Keycloak Admin API documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [@dreamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64247629/1366871), you need to count that from the response of `GET /{realm}/groups/{id}/members`.

I am using `jq`.. then my script is:

```bash
curl  .... ${url}/${realm}/groups/${id}/members | jq '. | length'
```